# ImageView frame is not changing while scrolling in Xcode 11.0 (11A420a)

Tags: swift, xcode11

I have a **UIView** on top of another **UIView**. In that top view I have a  **UIImageView** and on top of that there is a **scrollVIew**. When scrolling it used to stretch the **imageView** frame calculating the scroll offset. Now updating to **Xcode 11.0 (11A420a)** this feature is not working even though nothing has changed. Any suggestion why ? Here is my **imageView** constraints:

[image]

and my **scrollViewDidScroll** function:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = 135 - (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y + 135)
    let h = max(120, 160 + y)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: h)
    NHBannerImageView.frame = rect
}
```

As you can see there is a **rect** variable which value changes depending on scroll but after that image frame is not changing.

I have downloaded the Xcode 10.3 and its working straight away, with the same configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your view layout might be solve this problem.  Add -

`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

in scrollViewDidScroll